# Is it possible to add filter effects into a Video file in Swift3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift, video, avfoundation, cifilter

I am developing a video editing kind of application in `Swift3` language Where I am merging multiple videos.. setting custom background sound, WaterMark and Fade In & Fade Out effect to the final merged video using `AVFoundation` framework.

Now my problem is I need to add filter effects like `Warm, cold, sepia/vintage` to the video... Is this possible to add such effects in `Swift iOS` using inbuilt libraries? I have searched in Google but not able to find proper solution:

[RGB range for cold and warm colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615029/rgb-range-for-cold-and-warm-colors)

http://flexmonkey.blogspot.in/2016/04/loading-filtering-saving-videos-in-swift.html

[How to create and add video filter like Instagram using AVFoundation framework - Swift programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689050/how-to-create-and-add-video-filter-like-instagram-using-avfoundation-framework)

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011110

Please advise me. Thank you!

Edited:

I tried using below code but it doesn't work.

```
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone")!
        let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: firstAsset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in


            let source = request.sourceImage.clampingToExtent()
            filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

            // Vary filter parameters based on video timing
            let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
            filter.setValue(seconds * 10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)


            let output = filter.outputImage!.cropping(to: request.sourceImage.extent)

            // Provide the filter output to the composition
            request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
        })
```

Comment: What from your second link (FlexMonkey) has you saying it isn't *"...the proper solution"*? You're lacking *details* as in "what have you tried"?

Comment: Thanks for the code. Two things. (1) You need to explain *what* isn't working - the expected result in a bit more detail, etc. But more importantly is (2) *CISepiaTone* doesn't have something called "inputRadius"! It's not in the documentation nor in the filter's attributes (I actually checked). https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CISepiaTone

Comment: Sorry for late response @dfd, I tried using my second link (FlexMonkey) so I got to know that they are getting image frames from video file and then they are applying image filter and in UIImageView itself they are displaying all image frames, which looks like a playing Video. But as the final output source video's audio is missing. Is there any other way to achieve this with the source video sound?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that. I work with *still* images, not video - and on that I'm surprised that a `UIImageView` yields good performance (I always use a `GLKView` and only convert my `CIImage` to a `UIImage` when saving/sharing). But yeah, since I use still images with no audio, I'm of little help. :-(

Comment: please look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51017511/how-to-add-watermark-on-final-video-after-merging-video-and-audio-asset-into-one

Comment: Hi @dfd, Are you around? I have a doubt here with VideoComposition, can possible for you to suggest?

Comment: HI @AnandGautam, Have you found the answer? I need help, as I'm not able to create New Question...

Comment: @Mr.AhtazazYes, use AVPlayerItem and add filter like playerItem.videoComposition = yourComposition (playerItem is an instance of AVPlayerItem)

Comment: @AnandGautam found any solution?